# Dependency error installing fontconfig-dbgsym under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, apt, fontconfig

I am trying to install fontconfig-dbgsym under Ubuntu 18.04 inside Docker, running on Docker for Mac.

I use the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring lsb-release
RUN \
    ( \
        echo "deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs) main restricted universe multiverse"; \
        echo "deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-updates main restricted universe multiverse"; \
        echo "deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-proposed main restricted universe multiverse"; \
    ) > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list 
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y fontconfig
RUN apt-get install -y fontconfig-dbgsym
```

Everything works except the last step, which fails with:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fontconfig-dbgsym : Depends: fontconfig (= 2.12.6-0ubuntu2.2) but 2.12.6-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y fontconfig-dbgsym' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

It complains the dependency `fontconfig=2.12.6-0ubuntu2.2` isn't installed, but it was successfully installed by the previous step.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html).

Comment: @IporSircer Thanks. That link says to run "ubuntu-bug", but it isn't installed and can't work out how to install it. But, I could use bugs.launchpad.net web interface to log bug – https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fontconfig/+bug/1805820

Comment: @Ipor, it would help if you took the time to check what’s going on before telling people to file bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn’t a bug, at least not in Ubuntu. You’ve added the “proposed” ddeb repository, without adding the corresponding deb repository. As a result, your candidate versions are mismatched.

You should remove the “proposed” line, unless you want to help test proposed packages before they’re released. You should also close the bug you filed ;-).